# Django : SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib with APNS

Tags: python, django, ssl, certificate, pem

I'm developing 'APNS function' with Django.

This is my code to send push notification to the ios device

```
    PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    apns = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file=PATH+'/app/certificate.pem')
    token_hex = 'UUID from ios Device'
    payload = Payload(alert="Hello World!", sound="default", badge=1)
    apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)
    return Response({'test'})
```

> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 522, in **init**
>       self._context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
>   SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2580)

Yes, I already did search for the same issue and I'm almost sure that my 'certificate.pem' file is correct.

But one of my guessing things, I didn't insert the password for that 'certificate.pem' file.

Is it the reason for that error?

If so , where should I put the password for it?

Anyone solving this error?

> 'SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib'

Answer (score 3):

It was because of 'certifcate.pem' file. I had misunderstood how to create the correct 'certificate.pem' file. I did follow the instruction from 'http://www.apptuitions.com/generate-pem-file-for-push-notification/'.

Then, I could make the difference although I have not succeeded in pushing and receiving notifications.

I wish this is helpful for those having the same error messages

Answer (score 0):

I got `.cer`, `.p12` and `.pem` from Apple.

What worked for me was:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in aps_development.cer -out cert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in private.p12 -out key.pem -nocerts
cat key.pem cert.pem > dev.pem
```

I haven't used the `.pem` from Apple. The method from the website ( http://www.apptuitions.com/generate-pem-file-for-push-notification/ ) did not work for some reason.